# How can I position thumbnail images in a particular pattern as I append them to a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-manipulation, image-gallery

I'm building a gallery of 150 thumbnail images and I'm using a jQuery script to place the images into a DIV and link them to larger versions:

```
function getImageThumb(number) {
return $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Plate ' + number + '" rel="{gallery: \'gal1\', smallimage: \'./Vol4/Small/tafel_' + number + '.jpg\', largeimage: \'./Vol4/Large/tafel_' + number + '.jpg\'}">' +
         '<img src="./Vol4/Thumbs/tafel_' + number + '.jpg" alt="Plate ' + number + '" width="100" height="150" border="0" /></a>');}

$(document).ready(function(){  
    for (var i=450; i<601; i++) {
    $(".pane").append(getImageThumb(i)); 
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is with positioning.  Each thumbnail is 100px by 150px and I want to arrange them in groups of 9 in this particular order:

```
01 02 03   10 11 12   19 20 21
04 05 06   13 14 15   22 23 24
07 08 09   16 17 18   25 26 27
```

The idea is that the finished DIV will be 300px by 450px and show only a single block of 9 images at a time.  The user can scroll to the left or right to see different groups of 9 thumbnails.  But when I create a DIV with those dimensions and run the script, it just overflows the bottom and I get three columns and 50 rows arranged like this:

```
01 02 03
04 05 06
07 08 09
10 11 12
13 14 15  and so forth
```

Can anyone show me a simple way to position the images into the correct pattern as I append them to the DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [modulus](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)  operator

```
var paneCount = 1;
for (var i=450; i<601; i++) {
    if ( i % 9 == 0 )
       paneCount ++;
    $(".pane"+paneCount).append(getImageThumb(i)); 
}
```

Comment: Excellent!  That was the bit I needed to solve the problem.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gKkW4/